# Jenkins - Upstream project dependency issue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

Here is something I want to achieve:

I have a jenkins project which has 4 upstream projects. But I don't want to trigger this project when the upstream jobs are done building, but I want the trigger the project via remote API, which then waits on upstream projects until they are done building, if these projects are building.

Lets say all the 4 upstream projects can build the source code from any branch passed via API, but I want the downstream project to start only when a specific branch is passed to these upstream projects.

Scenario:

Lets say I have two clusters A and B, for the sake of this question, I want to deploy my code to cluster A, i.e front end and backend code. Now I have a project to build front end and 1 project to build backend (these two projects can build code for cluster A and B, based on the branch passed). Now, I have two deploy projects for cluster A which will deploy front end and backend. So, when I pass a branch to build code for cluster A, it will trigger the build projects. But now I only want these two deploy projects to start when this specific branch was passed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the builds remotely then use the Jerkins cli - I have found it very useful http://jenkinshost:8080/cli

You need to get the ssh key config right, add the public key of the user running the cli to the user you want to run the job in Jenkins using the Jenkins user configuration (not on the command line

Test key setup with

```
java -jar jenkins=cli.jar -s http://jenkinshost:8080 who-am-i
```

This should then report which user will be used to run the build in Jenkins

---

But I think you can use the Conditional Build Step plugin for your problem

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin

This will allow you to put a conditional wrapper around a build step i.e.

```
if branch==branchA then
  trigger step - deploy to clusterA

if branch==branchB then
  trigger step - deploy to clusterB
```

---

Personally I find this plugin a bit clunky and it makes the job config page a little messy

Another solution I came up with was to always call the child job and then let it decide if it runs.

So I have a script step at the start of the child job to see if it should run

```
if [${branch}="Not the right branch name" ] ; then
  echo "EXIT_GREEN"
  exit 1
fi
```

You have now failed this job which would cause the parent job to go red but by using the Groovy Postbuild plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin you can add a post build step like this

```
if (manager.logContains(".*EXIT_GREEN.*")) {
    manager.addBadge("info.gif","This job had nothing to do")
    manager.build.@result = hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS
}
```

Child job has run green (with an info icon against the build) but has actually not done anything. Obviously if the branch is one you want deploy then the first script step does not run the `exit 1` and the job continues as normal